# Problem with java

Tags: command-line, java, programming, 22.10, jre

jre1.8.0-51 is about to be reinstalled, but its archive cannot be found.
This error keeps showing up even after restarting the laptop. I tried to download the same jre version but it didn't pass through the terminal.

Comment: [EOL](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2023-June/000291.html)

Comment: and new problem. when I try to update the applications with the command sudo apt update and sudo apt update -y, terminal shows me: 404 Not Found [IP:

Comment: Looks like it isn't a new, but the same problem. Perhaps you can use another update mirror that still has repositories for 22.10.

Comment: and another one. Software updater won't run

Comment: Okay I give up now even the browser won't start